# How to run installer made by install4j on Mac in terminal?

Tags: macos, install4j

I'm trying to run installed dmg package (created by install4j) on OS X from remote terminal. Could you please help me to create a proper command for that?

I have 2 executable artifacts, one for windows and one for mac. For windows I already figured out how to do it, looks like this:

> my_product.exe -VadminPassword=password
>   -VadminPasswordConfirmed=password - -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=/install4j.log

I'm trying to do the same thing for MacOS by using such command:

> sudo /Volumes/my_product.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
>   -VadminPassword=password -VadminPasswordConfirmed=password -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=/install4j.log -c

But it doesn't work

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: Console mode is currently not supported on Mac OS X

Comment: I found the problem. I needed to use -q instead of -c.